# Naming convention for interface / class / mockClass in Java?

Tags: java

I'm creating a mock class for a `Lexer` object, and I think I may need to do some refactoring. I have two options:

1. Create an interface `Lexer`, and rename the current `Lexer` to something like `RealLexer`. Have `MockLexer` implement `Lexer`, and method calls take anything of type `Lexer`. I dislike that my precious `Lexer` class is now renamed to something that has no meaning if you don't know that there's a mock class.
2. Create an interface `LexerInterface` (which I already dislike, since it has `Interface` in its name), but allowing myself to keep the current `Lexer` the way it is. `MockLexer` then implements `LexerInterface`. Another downside is that method calls take `LexerInterface` as params.

Both options smell bad to me, so I figured I'd let standards decide for me. Has anyone had experience with this?

Comment: Why `RealLexer`?  Just name your `MockLexer` whatever you want since it'll only be used for testing.  Then maybe a `Lexer` interface and a `DefaultLexer` for a default impl

Comment: Well I like MockLexer since it immediately tells a maintainer that it's only to be used for Mock tests. But I do like "Default" rather than "Real".

Comment: True, it is good practice to append mock objects with `Mock`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd definitely vote for using `Lexer` as your interface name. How about adding some information about *how* or *why* your implementation does its thing as part of the name?
E.g.:

- `StringParsingLexer`
- `TokenizingLexer`
- `SingleThreadedLexer`
- `{ThirdPartyLibraryName}DelegatingLexer`

Also, do you really need to be explicitly constructing a `MockLexer`? Using a framework like [Mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html) can make your testing considerably easier and faster; You can get started as easily as:

```
Lexer mockLexer = Mockito.mock(Lexer.class);

Mockito.when(mockLexer.doFoo()).thenReturn("bar");
```

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation, as I stated in the comments, is to use `Lexer` for your interface and `DefaultLexer` for the default implementation.  This pattern is used quite frequently and as such is very understandable to anyone who will be maintaining your code.  As for the mock object, it would also be understandable to name this something like `MockLexer`.

As an example of a naming convention that Java uses:

`javax.swing.table.TableModel` is an interface
`javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel` is an abstract class implementing `TableModel`
`javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel` is an implementation of `AbstractTableModel`.

There is however, no recommendation in the [Java Codding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367) outside of using capital letters, nouns, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use option 1 - interfaces called `Lexer`, with default implementations called either `DefaultLexer` or `LexerImpl`. I like this, because I think it lets you talk about the classes easily - if you have multiple implementations of `Lexer`s, then their concrete names can describe the implementation type - eg `NativeLexer` or `TreeBasedLexer` or whatever. As a commenter mentioned, then your mock class (if you have one) can follow this pattern with a name like `MockLexer`.

However, with mocking libraries [such as the excellent Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/), you can mock concrete classes anyway - so you no longer need to use interfaces everywhere in order to test things easily. Here is the example they give [in their documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html):

```
//You can mock concrete classes, not only interfaces
LinkedList mockedList = mock(LinkedList.class);
```

That said, I would still recommend using interfaces instead of tying method signatures to concrete classes, because then things that use  `Lexer` do not need to be tied to the implementation - this can be a massive gain in maintainability (eg if you need to have multiple implementations later).

Answer (score 1):

In my experience there are two standards.

1. "Tag" your interface.  (`ILexer`, `LexerInterface`, etc)
2. Use the name for your interface and use a different name for the concrete implementation.

I know these are already the options you presented.  The trouble is, not one of them is firmly the "standard."

I **strongly** prefer option 2).  A class name for an object should tend to be a noun that fits within the context of an "is-a" sentence.  It feels weird to say that an object "is-a" `LexerInterface` whereas it is natural to say that an object "is-a" `DefaultLexer`.

Since ultimately my class or interface name represents a type, I shy away from "meta" information in a class or interface name.